# How can I get the symbols in a package at the time the package is defined?

Tags: perl, package

In a Perl program I'm working on, the user can specify a Perl module to be loaded which is expected to define a couple (a variable number) of  variables. The Perl program then processes these variables, basically treating the package as a plain hash except that the values are all in a namespace. Doing so works fine, i.e. this program prints '2':

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package P {
    my $k1 = 'v1';
    my $k2 = 'v2';
};

my $n = scalar keys %P::;
print "Number of entries: $n\n";
# print $P::x;
```

However, uncommenting the last line makes the program print '3'. I.e. the sheer mentioning of a variable in the package seems to add it to the symbol table.

Is there a way to get the symbol table for a package as it is defined, such that the symbol table consists of just two entries?

Comment: Perhaps, but possibly more important question is why do you want to do that, and is there a better way to it.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like an [`XY problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would be wise to reiterate what you're trying to accomplish and why. Also - turn on 'strict' and 'warnings' please.

Comment: @Сухой27 I'm working on an interactive Perl debugger (partially written in Perl itself, partly in C++) which allows users to load 'configurations' stored as Perl modules. The configurations are basically sets of key-value pairs. The configuration keys should be namespaced (that's why they are not stored in a plain hash but rather a package which is then often treated like a hash). The program needs the total set of settings _as stored on disk_ for different purposes (e.g. when deciding whether the settings on disk changed, or when deciding which settings to write out).

Comment: Single hash inside package works as expected, https://eval.in/882758

Comment: @Сухой27 Yes indeed, just the hash name `h` is a bit ugly there. For what it's worth, I also considered changing the configurations such that the namespacing is not done via `package` but rather via the name of the hash. The only nuisance is that you'd end up writing `$myProfile{color}` instead of `$MyProfile::color`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package variables encountered at compile-time will be added to the stash at compile time. So your workarounds are to evaluate the stash in the compile phase

```
package P {
    $k1 = 'v1';
    $k2 = 'v2';
};

BEGIN {    
    my $n = scalar keys %P::;
    print "Number of entries: $n\n";  # 2
}
print $P::x;
```

or to define other package variables at run-time

```
package P {
    $k1 = 'v1';
    $k2 = 'v2';
};

my $n = scalar keys %P::;
print "Number of entries: $n\n";    # 2
print eval '$P::x';
$n = scalar keys %P::;
print "Number of entries: $n\n";    # now 3
```

Comment: Ah, thanks - it didn't occur to me that I could use `BEGIN` on the main module, too - that helped!